# Strange behavior of mysql when group using date function

Tags: mysql

Mysql seems to return wrong result when using  COUNT(DISTINCT...) and GROUP BY DATE(...).
I am grouping by "record_date" column and I expect to see distinct values in the result set, but this is not the case. Also I am not able to order the result for some reason.

I do not know what is causing this behavior of MySQL.

**My table:**

```
CREATE TABLE `test_table` (
`test_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment,
`rid` varchar(50) default NULL,
`rid_test_id_ppl` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
`record_time` datetime default NULL,
PRIMARY KEY  (`test_id`),
UNIQUE KEY `uid` (`rid`),
KEY `rid_test_id_ppl` (`rid_test_id_ppl`),
KEY `record_time` (`record_time`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=1 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

**My Query:**

```
  SELECT DATE(`record_time`) AS record_date
       , COUNT( DISTINCT rid_test_id_ppl ) AS dubl
    FROM test_table
GROUP BY record_date
ORDER BY record_date ASC
```

**My Result:**

```
+------------+-------+
| record_date| dubl  |
+------------+-------+
| NULL       | 58569 |
| 2013-08-21 |  6052 |
| 2013-08-22 | 19180 |
| 2013-08-23 |     1 |
| 2013-08-22 |  7632 |
| 2013-08-23 |     1 |
| 2013-08-22 |  1300 |
| 2013-08-23 | 16458 |
| NULL       | 54996 |
| 2013-08-22 |     1 |
| NULL       |  1750 |
| 2013-08-21 |  2221 |
+------------+-------+
12 rows in set (0.36 sec)
```

**My Result, when I remove only the "DISTINCT" keyword:**

```
+------------+--------+
| record_date| dubl   |
+------------+--------+
| NULL       | 121134 |
| 2013-08-21 |   8275 |
| 2013-08-22 |  28130 |            
| 2013-08-23 |  16694 |
+------------+--------+
4 rows in set (0.30 sec)
```

Edit: My MySQL version is 5.0.45. 
Edit: The result set in both cases is copy-pasted. One more strange thing is that I got no ordering of the results in the first query.

Comment: "I am grouping by "record_date" column and I expect to see distinct values in the result set, but this is not the case" --- you're grouping by `record_date` and selecting by `DATE(record_date)`. If you remove `DATE()` function you'll see the entries are distinct

Comment: This behavior is highly unexpected and would indicate a bug in MySQL.  Are you sure this is correct?  If so, you should include more information about the version of MySQL and post this on dba.stackexchange.com.  By the way, the second results are quite suspicious because they are not ordered, suggesting that the queries are different.

Comment: @Gordon Linoff: it's highly unlikely there is such a dramatic bug for such a trivial query.

Comment: Can you create a self-contained test case on SQLFiddle? I agree with Gordon that this sounds like a bug of your specific MySQL version. I don't see this behaviour with a quick (and dirty) test-case on 5.5.8

Comment: @zerkms you are wrong! If you read carefully the code you will see, that record_date is alias for DATE(record_time), so I am not selecting by DATE(record_date) but  by DATE(record_time). Maybe the query looks trivial, but unfortunately it isn't.

Comment: @zerkms is correct - referencing of column aliases only works in an ORDER BY - you are in fact still referencing the original column.

Comment: @StephLocke you can use alias in GROUP BY, ORDER BY, or HAVING clauses to refer to the column. See the MySQL manual: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/problems-with-alias.html

Comment: Fair enough - later on in that then it solves your problem by saying 'Elsewhere in the statement, quoted references to the alias must use identifier quoting or the reference is treated as a string literal'

Comment: @StephLocke if you read carefully the statement you just pasted you will see that it has nothing to do with my case. Hint: It says "quoted references" must use "identifier quoting".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @a_horse_with_no_name suggested I imported the table with the data in MySQL version 5.5.24 Everything works as expected. Now i see distinct dates in the result set and sorting works just fine.